# CSS Grid Child Image overflowing

Tags: html, css, image, css-grid

Grid with 3 column Layout containing Title and image, but grid height is limited using `grid-auto-rows`.

```
<div class="app-list suggestions">
  <article>
    <div class="title">A App</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="title">B App</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180" />
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="title">C App </div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x220" />
  </article>
</div>
```

Css

```
.suggestions {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 150px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2.5em;
}

.suggestions > article {
  padding: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
  background-color: white;
}

article {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
}

img {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

[image]

How to make sure image take available space, while maintaining the aspect ratio?

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
}
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.suggestions {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 150px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2.5em;
}

.suggestions > article {
  padding: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
  background-color: white;
}

article {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-list suggestions">
  <article>
    <div class="title">A App</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="title">B App</div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180" />
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="title">C App </div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x220" />
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: your snippet is working fine

Comment: What is your goal, to prevent the overflow or to make the row expand to fit the content? You can prevent overflow with `overflow: hidden;` and you can remove `grid-auto-rows: 150px;` to allow the items to expand to fit the content.

Comment: @dippas after asking the question I added overflow:hidden, n it worked somehow

Comment: @TedWhitehead ya overflow: hidden is what was required. thank you